# server calls goes in infinite loop in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

At particular page in the project, I get output on the page.
When I refresh the page then also I get the same output. This is absolutely correct.
But when I refresh the page third time it shows busy browser and never return anything on the page. I am using tomcat server, hibernate, spring.
Due to busy browser and it never show anything ever, I have to restart the tomcat server.
 
Now history repeats. Third refresh make browser busy which doesn't fetch anything.
Is there any problem in hibernate ?
You first question would be like, what logs you are getting?
I see nothing in the log.

Comment: Provide the relevant code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: have you tried debugging it to see what happens? is the third request really getting stuck or are you not closing the connection and are out of connections in the 3rd time?

but i can't judge without enough code. provide us any and then we might be able to tell you something :)